# Check radio button if user already selected gender which is stored in database

Tags: java, spring-mvc

If gender==male is already in the DB then check radio button.

If gender is not stored in database then give option to select it.

Same with female gender

```
<c:when test="${sessionScope.player.gender=='male'}">
```

Male

```
<c:when test="${sessionScope.player.gender=='null'}">
    <form:radiobutton path="gender" value="male"/>Male
    </c:when>
    //if gender==female is already in DB then check radio button
    <c:when test="${sessionScope.player.gender=='female'}">
    <form:radiobutton path="gender" value="male" checked="true"/>Male
    </c:when>

 <c:when test="${sessionScope.player.gender=='null'}">
    <form:radiobutton path="gender" value="male" />Male
    </c:when>
```

But I am getting an exception.

Comment: so what is the exception? and where is the backing code? Post a [mcve]

Comment: tanks but i solve by:<c:choose>
   <c:when test="${sessionScope.player.gender=='male'}">
  <form:radiobutton path="gender" value="male"  checked="true"/>Male
  <form:radiobutton path="gender" value="female" />female
  </c:when>
 <c:when test="${sessionScope.player.gender=='female'}">
  <form:radiobutton path="gender" value="male"/>Male
  <form:radiobutton path="gender" value="female" checked="true"/>female
  </c:when>
 <c:otherwise>
  <form:radiobutton path="gender" value="male"/>Male
  <form:radiobutton path="gender" value="female" />female
  </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>

Comment: Improve formatting and spelling to make more readable.